# Is is possible to simply add optional dependencies in a module?

Tags: drupal, module, drupal-7

I'm creating a drupal module and I'm using the `country_get_list()` function from the module locale.

What I want is to prompt the user to enable the locale module to improve his experience but he can refuse.

In the doc https://drupal.org/node/542202 I see nothing about optional dependencies, only required dependencies with `dependencies[] = locale`

If my code I have something like that:

```
if(module_exists('locale')) {
    $form['locale'] = array(
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#title' => t('Locale'),
      '#options' => country_get_list(),
    );
  } else {
    $form['locale'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('Locale'),
    );
  }
```

Is there an easy way to do that with `optional_dependencies[] = locale` for example in my .info file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no .info file based method to define optional dependencies.

`module_exists` is usually used in such cases before calling a foreign code.

You can implement `hook_requirements` to show a message in the status report asking users to use the particular module for better experience.

Answer (score 1):

Support in https://drupal.org/node/820054 will help to get this in for Drupal 8.